# Bloom an ament_python package with Pip Dependencies

Tags: ros, python, pip, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having trouble with blooming a `rolling` package, possibly because of its pip dependencies.

- [Failing buildfarm job](https://build.ros2.org/view/Rsrc_uF/job/Rsrc_uF__tf_transformations__ubuntu_focal__source/5/console)
- [source repo](https://github.com/DLu/tf_transformations)
- [release repo](https://github.com/DLu/tf_transformations_release/tree/upstream)

Key error:

```
fatal: Remote branch debian/ros-rolling-tf-transformations_1.0.0-1_focal not found in upstream origin
...
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', 'clone', '--branch', 'debian/ros-rolling-tf-transformations_1.0.0-1_focal', '--depth', '1', '--no-single-branch', 'https://github.com/DLu/tf_transformations_release.git', '/tmp/sourcedeb/source']' returned non-zero exit status 128.
```

That branch doesn't exist in my release repo. I'm guessing its because of this line of the bloom execution:

```
==> git-bloom-generate -y rosdebian --prefix release/rolling rolling -i 1 --os-name debian --os-not-required
No platforms defined for os 'debian' in release file for the 'rolling' distro. This os was not required; continuing without error.
```

I bring up the pip dependencies because I got warnings about my pip dependency:

```
Key 'python-transforms3d-pip' resolved to '['transforms3d']' with installer 'pip', which does not match the default installer 'apt'.
Failed to resolve python-transforms3d-pip on ubuntu:focal with: Error running generator: The Debian generator does not support dependencies which are installed with the 'pip' installer.
python-transforms3d-pip is depended on by these packages: ['tf_transformations']
<== Failed
Some of the dependencies for packages in this repository could not be resolved by rosdep.
<== The following generator action reported that it is missing one or more
    rosdep keys, but that the key exists in other platforms:
'['/usr/bin/git-bloom-generate', '-y', 'rosdebian', '--prefix', 'release/rolling', 'rolling', '-i', '1', '--os-name', 'ubuntu']'

If you are absolutely sure that this key is unavailable for the platform in
question, the generator can be skipped and you can proceed with the release.
Skip generator action and continue with release [y/N]?
```

So how do I bloom my Python-y package correctly? I get that [Native packages are preferred](https://answers.ros.org/question/313811/bloom-generate-debian-package-with-pip-only-dependency/) but there's got to be some way to use pip, otherwise why even support it in the rosdistro?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380279/bloom-an-ament_python-package-with-pip-dependencies/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2021-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Bloom an ament_python package with Pip Dependencies

unless something has changed recently, packages with `pip` dependencies can't be released through the ROS buildfarm, afaik because the `dpkg-buildpackage` pipeline doesn't allow / support it.

> but there's got to be some way to use pip, otherwise why even support it in the rosdistro?

you're referring to the `-pip` entries in the `rosdep` db? Those are there to facilitate builds from-source in a Catkin/Colcon workspace (installing dependencies using `rosdep`).

---

Edit: well, in ROS 1 we had [catkin_virtualenv](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin_virtualenv), which sort-of made it possible to release Python pkgs with `pip` dependencies. But that really only worked well for leaf packages, which I don't believe `tf_transformations` is.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2021-06-15**:
What if I add it as an `install_requires` entry in my setup.py?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-16**:
I don't believe that changes anything. What I've seen other people do is *vendor in* their dependencies. That's basically what `catkin_virtualenv` automated.

It will mean users will get your dependencies "for free" with your own package, but without those dependencies being known to their package managers. That can lead to some interesting situations with multiple installations of those dependencies and the potential resulting conflicts.

A `venv` avoids that, but as I wrote above, I don't believe that would be possible for a non-leaf pkg.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-16**:
Perhaps @nuclearsandwich can add something here.

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2021-11-05**:\

> What if I add it as an install_requires entry in my setup.py?

Then building that package will likely fail on the buildfarm when dh_python executes the installation and one of the modules listed in `install_requires` is missing.

**Comment by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) on 2021-11-05**:
@gvdhoorn is exactly right about pip packages being in rosdep to facilitate workspace builds that use them and bloom warns you that they aren't supported exactly because the deb and rpm pipelines cannot use pypi to satisfy system package dependencies.

If the pip packages are required for the package to function, that package can't be released. It would be possible to release other packages in the same repository by ignoring the pip-dependent package, but of course if the other packages depend on pip transitively that won't work.

ROS packages do not have any way to represent optional or opportunistic dependencies so if the pip package is used during testing (sometimes the case) and not needed during runtime then it's possible to patch the package.xml at bloom time to omit the pip package but that relies on it being a test-only dependency.